Buoyant force: lead block on top of styrofoam block floating on water, then swap de blocks around
I have a quick question related to the buoyant force.
A block of lead is placed on a piece of styrofoam in water. In this case, the water comes up to the top of the styrofoam. If we now turn it over (so the block of lead is at the bottom), will it 1 (sink), 2 (the water comes back up to the top of the styrofoam), or 3 (float, styrofoam sticks out of the water.
What I know (or at least think):
The buoyant force must stay the same because the total mass of the lead + styrofoam doesn't change, so the mass of the displaced water is the same.
But then I get confused because lead has a higher density than styrofoam, so does it sink deeper into the water? On the other hand, I just said the mass of displaced water is the same, so then the volume of displaced water is the same, so shouldn't the lead with styrofoam sink just as deep as in the first scenario?
So I suppose I think that the answer is option three: the water level stays at the edge of the lead and the styrofoam sticks out of the water.

You seem to have a picture of the composite object in your head. You could help other people to help you understand the question if you would draw that picture and add it to your question. When you draw it, it might help if you know that volume of the styrofoam brick will have to be just a bit less than eleven times the volume of the lead brick if you want the combined object to float in water. If the volume of the styrofoam is any less than that, then the average density of the composite object will be greater than the density of water, and the object will sink.

A composite object will float as long as its average density is less than or equal to the density of water, regardless of how the mass is distributed (though it may be initially unstable depending on how its orientated when placed in the water).
Since the buoyancy force is the same regardless of whether the lead or styrofoam is on top, the volume of the submerged portion of the combination of the styrofoam and led will be the same whether the styrofoam is on top or bottom.
Hope this helps.

Yes I think I get it now, so this means that I was right and the water level will be up to the edge between the lead and the styrofoam right?
Thanks

The submerged volume will be the same. However, exactly where the water level is depends on how much foam and how much lead there is, which you didn't specify.

The buoyancy force is the force the water exerts upward on the styrofoam/lead. Suppose you remove the styrofoam/lead, leaving a hole in the water. The buoyancy force is the pressure over that surface that will fill in the hole. If you fill the hole with water, the weight of the water balances the buoyancy force over the surface.
A bigger or deeper surface will exert a bigger upward force. If you put styrofoam/lead just touching the surface, the buoyancy force is too small to hold it up. It will push deeper into the water until it digs a hole big enough where the buoyancy force is as large as the weight of the styrofoam/lead. This will be when the hole is big enough that the weight of the water needed to fill it is a big as the weight of the styrofoam/lead. You have set up the problem so that this is the same volume as the styrofoam. The lead stays above the surface.
If you turn the styrofoam/lead over, the same buoyancy force is needed to float it. The shape of the hole is different, but it will have the same volume so the same weight of water is needed to fill it. Since the volume of styrofoam/lead below the water is the same as before, the volume of styrofoam/lead above the water is the same. This time the volume above contains only styrofoam. That volume is the same as the volume of the lead.
